# Attach to tangle, invalid response error

Tags: wallet, attach-to-tangle

I am using the official IOTA GUI wallet (currently version 2.5.4). I am having problems with the "Attach to Tangle" function. I always get the error message "invalid response".

I already changed the settings in `Tools` > `Edit Node Configuration` to recommended values but it still doesn't work.

Do I need to "Attach to Tangle" to receive IOTA? And what does the "invalid response" error actually mean?

Comment: try other nodes (connect to another host).

Comment: it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the node your wallet is talking to did not return the expected response to your API call. Usually it is a problem with the node and the issue can be fixed by changing to another one.

The Bitfinex node has been known to report "I'm depressed, leave me be." during times of heavy network load, which could cause this error.

Comment: it doesn't work!
I changed my hosts and it still don't work, I also cannot send IOTAS to a adress

Comment: brandart, it's likely then that you have firewall or some other issue on your side which is modifying the response. To diagnose the problem, you should write some code to send an API call to a node and see what happens, as in https://iota.stackexchange.com/a/288/420. But this is somewhat outside the scope of SE I think.

Comment: firewall did'nt solve my problem